# Does vscode create a system PATH to api after I add it to dependencies(or library)?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I don't know how importing api work. Does vscode create a system **PATH** to api after I add it to maven dependencies(or library)? Then when compile java, compiler finds `.jar` in system **PATH**. Isn't it?

 Example, in pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I update the project, does VSCode create a system PATH to `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` ? Then I import the servlet in java, the compiler finds it in system PATH. Isn't it?

Comment: Er, no. The jars are on the classpath ...

Comment: Must I set classpath to .jar? Or vscode did it when update project? I ask this question because I got an error "package javax.servlet does not exist" when I complie java. Please help me.

Comment: I've answered your another question that the another dependency solves your error. Please have a try.